# PayPal NVP Error: CURL Request failed: SSL connect error (35)

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am getting this error when connecting the PayPal (NVP) API;
CURL Request failed: SSL connect error(35)

This means that I can't connect because I am probably using SSL3, how can I fix this issue as I can't go live without testing.. Do I have to change my server or can I fix it in the CURL request?

Comment: Who are you hosting with?  The problem resides in the hosting environment.  If you tell them this is happening they should be able to fix it for you.

Comment: but I need to know what needs to be changed as it is a dedicated server

Comment: You probably just need to update the OpenSSL version on your server.  You'll need to research the POODLE vulnerability.  There's lots of info about it.

Comment: i too face this problem but later investigate i added tlsv1.2 support in curl by adding this line  `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);` 6  is for  tlsv1.2

Answer (score 3):

I have the workaround solution which you facing now(i too facing the problem from last week with sandbox environment) now you should try something like in your curl call

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6); //6 is for TLSV1.2
```

**DETAILS**

**CURLOPT_SSLVERSION 
One of CURL_SSLVERSION_DEFAULT (0), CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1 (1), CURL_SSLVERSION_SSLv2 (2), CURL_SSLVERSION_SSLv3 (3), CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_0 (4), CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_1 (5) or CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2 (6)**

.

> Note:
>       Your best bet is to not set this and let it use the default. Setting it to 2 or 3 is very dangerous given the known vulnerabilities
>   in SSLv2 and SSLv3.

CREDITS: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Hope it helps to someone.

Comment: I have been trying to fix my issue for about 5 hours and finally i used this code and it worked.. can u tell me exactly why this error happens? do i need to downgrade my version of php? i am using 5.6... what exactly does the following code do?  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6); .. thanks so much

Comment: actually paypal has upgraded tls v1.2, it can be fix by check with hosting provider or another case will be to set the curl option ssl version to 6 for to force version tls 1.2

Answer (score 1):

We also faced the same issue, and we fixed this issue by setup the SSL to our server and created ca-certificate and then added ca-certification path in our curl call like the following example.

```
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
    CURLOPT_CAINFO =>'cert.pem',
```

NOTE: Please check your curl version and update it to latest one.

Server admin people may aware of this, like how to setup SSL as well as how to obtain the ca certificate.

ALL THE BEST,

Answer (score 0):

curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1);