# Not receiving the transaction string from paypal sandbox after a successful transaction

Tags: php, curl, paypal

I am creating an ecommerce site for digital downloads however there is a problem with the transaction data received back from paypal. Can you think of anything i am doing wrong?
I have a sandbox business account and i have gone into website payment preferences in my account and turned auto return to on and payment data transfer to on. I have set a return url which is working successfully. I have then received an identity token which i have inserted into my code below.

I have used the following code and been successful before (about a year ago) on a different website however it doesn't seem to be working this time ie when i try to print out the results to the console it says "false"

I am able to successfully pay on the paypal site and then i am successfully redirected to the correct URL with a query string in the browser as follows:

http://www.sarahswebsite.com/confirmation.php?tx=05D40838LW579215A&st=Completed&amt=5%2e00&cc=EUR&cm=MUZIC-1463960113&item_number=

My Php:

```
<?php   
 $api_endpoint= "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
    $transID = $_GET['tx'];
    $atID= 'AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31A7Ez9-tDKvj2MIuwN2MJ0r';


    $cmd = "_notify-synch";
    $nvp_string = "tx=" . urlencode($transID) . "&at=" . urlencode($atID) . "&cmd=" . urlencode($cmd);
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $api_endpoint);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvp_string);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);     
    curl_close($curl);
?>
```

Javascript

```
window.onload = function(){

        window.name_value_pairs= <?php echo json_encode($result); ?>;
        console.log(window.name_value_pairs); 
    //this used to print out the string of name value pairs however now it is printing 'false'.
}
```

Edit:
I have more information on this. it is a curl error:
35 SSL connect error.

any ideas on a solution for this? thanks

Comment: Are you aware of the Paypal REST SDK for PHP? It might make your life easier: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/

Comment: Is your Javascript statement in a PHP code block? Otherwise $result won't be in scope.

Comment: @DeeDee thanks.. no its in a script tag further down in my html.. it returns "false".. it would return undefined or null if nothing was stored in the variable.. it used to display the results from paypal. im not sure why it doesnt work anymore.. its either my code or i've missed something in my paypal sandbox account settings or something.

Comment: @zulus thanks for the edit. it was somebody else who added that tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix for this after reading the following post:

[PayPal NVP Error: CURL Request failed: SSL connect error (35)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34932410/paypal-nvp-error-curl-request-failed-ssl-connect-error-35)

I added the following two lines to my curl code and it is working perfectly now. I'm not completely sure on why it works now and didn't before however i think it is to do with the version of php i am using (5.6) or paypal have changed their security protocols.

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6); //6 is for TLSV1.2
```